# Откуда берётся пробел перед числом при его присвоении переменной его значения из ячейки?

Tags: excel, vba

Мне нужно открывать макросом существующие на жёстком диске файлы по их точным именам, которые состоят из одной постоянной и двух переменных частей. Например, "`25-й файл. Срок до 2022.09.25`", где "`25`" - первая переменная часть, "`-й файл. Срок до 2022.`" - постоянная, а "`09.25`" - вторая переменная. "`25`" и "`09.25`" у меня хранится на листе-справочнике, где каждому номеру файла приведён в соответствие свой дедлайн.
Проблема в том, что при присвоении переменной значения из ячейки справочника перед числом появляется пробел. Т.е., вместо "`25`" я получаю " `25`". Наличие этого пробела приводит к тому, что нужный мне файл не может быть найден и открыт.
Вот код, который поможет воспроизвести ситуацию:

```
Option Explicit

Sub str_test()
Dim str_srt As String

ActiveCell.Value = "25"
str_srt = Str(ActiveCell.Value)
Debug.Print "." & str_srt & "."
    
End Sub
```

Видно, что после выполнения кода в окне Immediate появляется " `25`" (с пробелом, наличие которого не предполагался), заключённые в точки.
Я пробовал хранить данные в справочнике в форматах String и Integer - никакой разницы.
Вопрос: **откуда берётся этот пробел**?
Зная ответ на вопрос, я, возможно, смогу бороться с этими пробелами...

Comment: Понял, что лечится при помощи Replace(), но по-прежнему не понимаю причину происхождения пробелов

Comment: Я уже лет 20 не писал макросы `VBA`, но насколько я помню конкатенация строк все же `+` а не `&` возможно в этом и проблема, `&` - это побитовая `И` т.е. оператор для работы с битами чисел (с символами тоже может работать теоретически)

Comment: Сцеплять строки можно операторами "+" и "&". Но с "+" надо аккуратнее, чтобы не нарваться на ошибку при  сцеплении числа и текста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробел появляется на этапе записи значения в переменную. Неявное преобразование типов.

В локализации *Excel* разделитель целой и дробной части числа - запятая, в *VBA* -  точка.

Давайте поиграемся.

```
str_srt = ",25"
Debug.Print "." & str_srt & "."
```

Результат: в сцепке то же значение - `.,25.`

Теперь пробуем взять значение с листа:

```
ActiveCell.Value = ",25"
str_srt = Str(ActiveCell.Value)
Debug.Print "." & str_srt & "."
```

Результат: `. .25.`. Откуда точка?!

Для VBA значение с запятой - это текст (записать в коде `0,25` или `,25` без кавычек не получится). Но! Умный VBA понимает, что такой текст взят с листа, он видит локализацию и сначала текст `,25` преобразовывает в число `0.25`, потом это число насильно пытается запихнуть обратно в текст )

При записи в текстовую переменную в мозгах *VBA* когнитивный диссонанс :) -  текст в число, число в текст... Зачем эти пляски? Число должно быть числом! Числа с текстом нормально сцепляются, ошибки не будет (можно предварительно записать значение в переменную *Long*):

```
Sub str_test2()
    Dim FirstPart As Long
    
    ActiveCell.Value = 25
    FirstPart = ActiveCell.Value
    Debug.Print "." & FirstPart & "."
End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ. Он многое прояснил.
Откуда точка - понятно. А откуда пробел??
В Вашем примере пробел появляется вместо нуля перед разделителем целой и дробной части. В таком случае, мой код должен возвращать пробел **после** числа, а не **до** него...

Comment: Нет, пробел не вместо нуля. Откуда он - не исследовал. Но понятно, что это результат преобразований типов данных. И надо, как в правильной медицине - не лечить, но проводить профилактику. Правильный режим питания, сна (читай - правильные данные) и т.д. :)

Comment: Пробел возникает как следствие использования функции [Str](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/str-function): "При преобразовании чисел в строки начальный пробел всегда резервируется для добавления знака числа. Для положительного числа возвращается строка с начальным пробелом (в этом случае подразумевается наличие знака плюса).".   Если вам все-таки понадобится явное преобразование, используйте `CStr()` - она не добавляет пробел.

Comment: О знаке - просто и явно, казалось  бы, но не знал. Спасибо

Comment: Элегантно, спасибо. Вы избавили меня от боли и страданий :-)